# Get y point from x given point hightcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to get y point from a given x point.
x point will not necesary be a point in chart, it can be between two points.
x point is a constant value, so is not clicked or seleted

[image]

In my case the given points for draw the graph are the red ones , but i would like to get green one knowing x value

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through points and try to find the one by searching `x` value. If the point is not found, calculate `y` value based on the next and the previous ones. The below algorithm should work fine for `line` series:

```
const x = 3;

const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {...});

const points = chart.series[0].points;
let prevX, nextX;
let prevY, nextY;
let y;

points.forEach((point, index) => {
  if (point.x === x) {
    y = point.y;
  }

  if (point.x > x && !prevX) {
    nextX = point.x;
    prevX = points[index - 1].x;

    nextY = point.y;
    prevY = points[index - 1].y;
  }
});

if (!y) {
  const xDiff = nextX - prevX;
  const yDiff = nextY - prevY;

  const unit = yDiff / xDiff;

  y = (x - prevX) * unit + prevY;
}

console.log(y);
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uavrmLhk/

Comment: i was thinking also into using this function from hightcharts: activeSerie.chart.pointer.findNearestKDPoint([activeSerie], false, {chartX: pointX}).y; but i don't know if it returns any point from the chart or just the points given for drawing the chart

Comment: Hi @kiusy, This method returns a point that is drawn on the chart. API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Pointer#findNearestKDPoint

Comment: but here i do not understand if it is one of the points that i use for draw the graph or, it can be one point of the graph with can be between two of the given points

Comment: Yes, it is one of the points that you use to draw the graph.